# Error 400 when build:android setting keystore manually

Tags: react-native, keystore, expo, android-build, android-keystore

We have an app previously built on phonegap and now migrated to React Native/Expo. We are trying to build the android .apk using the keystore we had before and we get the following error:

[image: screenshot]

I know that the problem is not with my .keystore, since through `expo fetch:android:keystore` I’ve got the keystore generated by EXPO and it gives me the same error!

Using `expo build:android` works fine, but I can’t deploy since the fingerprints doesn’t match with the app I have already published.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hitting this too. Don't know if it's because I just updated to Expo version 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with expo-cli `2.7.1` and it's fixed on `2.7.2`. So just needed to update my cli version!